# Memebership get user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am new in asp.net memebership. I am facing a problem. There is a table in db named profile in which a column named PropertyValueStrings have a value. I want to get user from Memberships table by using PropertyValueStrings. Like

```
select * from Memberships where UserId = (select UserId from Profiles where PropertyValueStrings=12 )
```

Is it possible in c#?

Comment: Yes it is. What do you think?

Comment: You can create custom membership, and just override everything you need.

Comment: You should try to accept some of the answers given to you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible. However, it is not recommended. The membership classes provide an excellent interface to list all the users, also you can fetch their roles and membership to each role using the membership APIs.

The reason why microsoft is providing this functionality is, you don't have to write the sql and deal with tables.

The role base security and profile service extensively use SQL and they are normal tables. You can query them exactly in the same way as you do on other tables.

Comment: Do you want an example of how to make a query on table using c# ? I hope you know the basics of ADO.Net

Comment: I know how to make query, But I am not able to understand that how to use above query same in c# page I am using edmx, VS-2012 mvc

Comment: You can make a query outside the edmx. Otherwise you can also add those tables in the data model. Unless and otherwise you make any changes to them, it will not harm the functionality of profile service.

Comment: Thanks to all I have got solution as                                 var AllUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>();               var obj = AllUsers.Select(user => ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName, true)).Where(profile => profile.GetPropertyValue("PropertName").ToString() == "Value").SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all I have got solution as

```
var AllUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>(); 
var obj = AllUsers.Select(user => ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName, true)).Where(profile => profile.GetPropertyValue("PropertName").ToString() == "Value").SingleOrDefault();
```

It return result as

select * from Memberships where UserId = (select UserId from Profiles where PropertyValueStrings=12 )